# GKE init container won't be able to connect GCP SQL after Anthos service Mesh Installation

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio, servicemesh, google-anthos-service-mesh

Once I have installed the **Anthos service mesh** in **private GKE autopilot cluster init container won't be able to connect GCP SQL RDS** however before anthos service mesh installation init container is able to connect GCP SQL RDS. Is anyone facing this type of issue if yes then please help here?

In the init container I'm trying to check connectivity by below command:
`until nc -w 5 <PRIVATE_IP> 3306; do echo "Waiting for the <PRIVATE_IP>..."; sleep 5; done`

Comment: Any chance you annotated the namespace where your SQL app is deployed?  Maybe you can show the output of `kubectl desc pod <SQL_APP_POD>"?

Comment: Init container is trying to connect GCP SQL RDS(GCP Managed service).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have mutual tls enabled ?
Can you try to edit the sidecar configuration ?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Sidecar
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: example
spec:
  outboundTrafficPolicy:
    mode: ALLOW_ANY
```